# Blazor routing with required and optional parameters

Tags: c#, url, razor, routes, blazor

I am a bit confused about blazor routing. One of the ways we can send a parameter in a route would be `@page "/FulfillOrder/{id:int}"` with a corresponding `[Parameter]` in the code section. The URL would look like "mypage.com/FulfillOrder/5".

I can also use query string "mypage.com/FulfillOrder/5?ship=Tardis" to add parameter and get the ship value via `QueryHelpers`.

My question is, why why and when should I use parameters/query string? When to use both? Are these two the only way or are there more?

Also kinda unrelated but is there a nicer way to construct the URL than just using interpolated strings and a NavLink component?

Comment: Your main question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819583/rest-query-string-vs-url-path

Comment: The second half of your question "nicer way to construct URL" is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c

Sanitizing your keys and values is particularly important to avoid malicious attacks etc.

Comment: @RJ Thanks, those did help somewhat. So essentially I should use the parameter approach under most circumstances, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Optional parameters aren't supported. However, we can use two `@page` directives to get the effect of optional parameters.

```
@page "/fullfillOrder"
@page "/fullfillOrder/{Id}"
```

The first `@page` directive allows navigation to the component without a parameter. The second `@page` directive receives the {Id} route parameter and assigns the value to the `Id` public property on the component class.

**Reference**: https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-route-parameters/